# GCP Cloud Shell IDE Open folder

Tags: google-cloud-shell

When I open cloud shell IDE, I can get the terminal to point to my GCP VM instance. However I cannot get the folder structure to shift to also look at the same VM.  It seems my home looks at my workspace (the given cloud shell environment with 5GB limit).  But I cannot open the VM folder structure I want to use in the IDE.

Is there a simple way of doing this, the documents given at

https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/workspaces

Do not talk about accessing VM folders.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SSH connection in order to connect you your VM instance:

- You can either connect in the Cloud Shell on the [VM instances page](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?_ga=2.62034348.1659644986.1626072340-163333918.1612439028&_gac=1.20582346.1626247320.CjwKCAjwlrqHBhByEiwAnLmYUGZ1uhpRtTMNeYcutmW5qcHsufQA3HJYaqrJ7Vizbk1wkeR-4x2f9hoCqNIQAvD_BwE) by clicking on the `SSH` button
- or if you'd like to connect through the GCP terminal, use the `gcloud compute ssh --project=PROJECT_ID --zone=ZONE VM_NAME` command.

Both methods are described in the [Connecting to Linux VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#gcloud) doc.

Comment: I am attempting to open my VM within Google Cloud's IDE as described here:

https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/workspaces 

This would be a new workspace within the IDE.  The issue seems to be that I am 'stuck' within the IDE to looking at the cloudshell rather than the VM I want to develop on.